# Notebook is booting too long

Tags: boot, xubuntu

I have (maybe 6 months old) Lenovo Think Pad E580 with Xubuntu 17 with two discs, SSD 250GB, and SATA 1TB.
Xubuntu is installed on SSD.
From the beginning, when I started the notebook, it started fast.
Now, after the start, the black screen is displayed and after a few minutes the Xubuntu logo appears and the system starts.

Comment: In a terminal, type `systemd-analyze blame`. Paste the first ten lines of output or so into your question.

Comment: 6.763s docker.service
6.283s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
3.611s virtualbox.service
2.862s dev-mapper-xubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
1.864s postfix@-.service
1.809s dev-loop18.device
1.670s dev-loop17.device
1.664s dev-loop16.device
1.620s dev-loop22.device
1.586s dev-loop20.device

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the output into it. In any case, this is not an indication of a long boot time.

Comment: My guess is the SSD is getting full, and it's showing up as sluggish running and slow boot times.

Comment: Can you also paste the content of /var/log/syslog in a code snippet?
Usually when the system slows down at boot is because some daemons fail to start and the boot hangs until they timeout.

Comment: Try to update drivers video, it may help